# In java, when reading in a file one character at a time, how do I determine EOF?

Tags: java, input, eof

I am having to read in a while and use an algorithm to code each letter and then print them to another file. I know generally to find the end of a file you would use readLine and check to see if its null. I am using a bufferedReader. Is there anyway to check to see if there is another character to read in? Basically, how do I know that I just read in the last character of the file?

I guess i could use readline and see if there was another line if I knew how to determine when I was at the end of my current line.

I found where the File class has a method called size() that supposidly turns the length in bytes of the file. Would that be telling me how many characters are in the file? Could i do `while(charCount<length)`  ?

Comment: While(I'm not at the last character of my file) { BufferedWriter.print(char) }

Comment: Is it you want to append to an existing file?

Answer (score 10):

I don't exactly understand what you want to do. I guess you may want to read a file character by character. If so, you can do:

```
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
int r;
while ((r = fileInput.read()) != -1) {
   char c = (char) r;
   // do something with the character c
}
fileInput.close();
```

[`FileInputStream.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29) returns `-1` when there are no more characters to read. It returns an `int` and not a `char` so a cast is mandatory.

Please note that this won't work if your file is in UTF-8 format and contains multi-byte characters. In that case you have to wrap the `FileInputStream` in an `InputStreamReader` and specify the appropriate charset. I'm omitting it here for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: But yes, I am wanting to real my file character by character, but obviously want to stop once i run out of characters

Comment: I know HOW to read in char by char. I just need to know when to stop

Comment: Oh I looked closer at the API and your answer is totally correct. Thanks! a -1 is returned "at the end of the stream"

Comment: OK, glad to know! Please consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: FileInputStream is a byte stream and should not be used for characters. Use FileReader for characters.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, buffers will return -1 if there are no characters left. So you could write:

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("filename"));
while (currentChar = in.read() != -1) { 
    //do something 
}
in.close();
```

Comment: Pretty much the same as @gdt1's answer above.

Comment: It's even wrong because of operator precedence. Fortunately in Java a `boolean` cannot be implicitly cast to a `char`, otherwise that code would cause a hell of a bug.